# How to deal with copy/xcopy from a virtual machine

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, vmware, file-transfer, xcopy

I'm working with several virtual machines, one of them being Windows 7.
I'd like to copy files from that machine to my machine (which is Windows XP).

Until now this is done using `CopyFileFromGuestToHost`, but I'd like to replace this using a simple `copy` or `xcopy` command.

This seems not to work, as you can see from following excerpts:

```
xcopy \\<machine_name>\\D\Logs\<filename> .
Invalid Drive specification

copy \\<machine_name>\\D\Logs\<filename> .
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

As far as the Invalid Drive specification is concerned, this most probably means that I need to share the directory `D:\Logs` (unfortunately this directory seems to be read-only, and every attempt to make it writeable is failing, due to an unknown reason (just a message box in Windows environment, nothing in the Windows application event log)).

As far as the Logon failure is concerned, does anybody know how I can add a username and password to the `copy` command?

In the meanwhile, I've found out that the virtual machine looks secured:
Guest isolation is set to "enabled, enabled".
"Enable VMCI" is not set

I believe that one of those last two settings is blocking the `copy` or `xcopy` commands. Does anybody know which of those settings need to be disabled in order for `xcopy` to pass?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is your networking set up on the guest?  Also, are both the guest and the host in the same workgroup?  You can make things a lot easier for yourself by using bridged networking, and placing both machines in the same workgroup.  Then, just treat the the same as you would two physical computers.

Comment: There are several ways to copy files between HOST and GUEST or between 2 GUESTS machines (with GUEST I mean the virtual boxed system). Check [this linux answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/508545/196535), some of the ideas may be directly applicable to the windows systems too. (BTW which virtualization software are you using?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to map a network drive to do that. Map drive to a specific path with user credentials and you are done. Then you can copy files as you wish.

Also, when accessing external resource you should use C$ or D$ as a drive, not only single letter. That is required by accessing drives by a network address like `\\computer\resource`.

Comment: I'm afraid this is too easy: in order to map a virtual remote directory to a drive letter, this remote directory needs to be shared, but when I try to setup a share, this seems not to be possible (and worst is, it just says `Your folder can't be shared.` without any indication). I wonder whether any `Guest Isolation` setting should be used in order to avoid this problem.

Comment: If you have administrator privileges you don't need to make the resource shared. That is why the specific credentials are needed.

Comment: I have managed solving the sharing issue. The biggest next problem was that the virtual name of the computer did not correspond with its actual name, but this problem is now solved too. As soon as I get the permission from the site, I'll reward your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "NET USE" command to specify user name and password to solve your second issue.

The syntax is below:

```
NET USE \\<SOURCE_VM_NAME>\DIR1 /u:<TARGET_VM_NAME>\<UserName> <PWD>
```

For example:

```
NET USE \\MY_VM\Builds /u:DEV_VM\Dominique cool
```